# Trouble getting element for d3 in Polymer

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, polymer, cubism.js

I'm trying to implement [cubism](http://square.github.io/cubism/) and I'm using [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) v2 in my [polymer](/questions/tagged/polymer) component.  The very first step is selecting the DOM element for the chart:

```
d3.select("#example1").call(function(div) {
...    
});
```

This returns the following error on line 1205 of `cubism.v1.js`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Upon inspecting the code, the `div` object has no id and the `innerHtml` value is *all* of my html (starting with `<head>` and ending with `</body>`).

I'm assuming this is due to polymer rendering `<div id='example1'></div>` after the code runs, but I don't know for sure.  I tried putting the `select` statement both in its own `<script>` tag under `<dom-module>` and in the `Polymer.ready` function.  Both have the same result.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing this:

```
d3.select("#example1").call(function(div) { .. }
```

to this:

```
var chart = self.$$('#example1');
d3.select(chart).call(function(div) { ... }
```

As documented here under [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding).

Answer (score 0):

In order to select a shadow DOM element(with an id, class, etc) in Polymer using D3V5, you can simply do following:

```
<div id="example"></div>

d3.select(this.$.example)
```